# Efficiently get Daily Sales for Whole Month from Google Analytics API

Tags: java, google-analytics

I am currently working getting Google Analytics Data for a client via the API. I am using a java library to do so located [here](https://github.com/brsanthu/google-analytics-java). I am trying to get the daily amount of sales for a given period of time [day,month week, year, etc].

The problem I have is the only way I seem to be able to get this information is to make a call to the Google Analytics API for each day, resulting in X days worth of calls to the API. Because of this, getting the information above as described takes a while and sometimes the results are missing data.

I call this command to get the sales multiple times

```
//start date and end date are the same for daily queries
result = analytics.data().ga().get(id, startDate, endDate, "ga:totalValue").execute();
```

Is there a way to do a batch job or a way to get a range into daily segments? I am using the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and have not found a way to do this efficiently. If not can I optimize what I am doing in any way? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query [time based dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time) - e.g. if you add ga:date as dimension you will get a row for each day with the selected metrics per day.